# How to work with Cache-Control using WebRequest and WebResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, microservices

Imagine a number of services in a Microservices architecture. Service A requests a response from service B and service B sets the `Cache-Control` header to `public, max-age=78261`.

Is there not a .NET way to work with the requested object and a "Cache" object of some sort?

One could think that there should/would be a `Cache` property in the `WebResponse` or `HttpWebResponse` class, interfacing the `Cache-Control` header.

**Is it really neccessary to parse the `Cache-Control` string, find the value and implement support for the header manually?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service B is indicating that it's data can be cached anywhere, such as on any downstream proxy servers if you are fronting the request through a CDN (edge-caching). Subsequent requests to Service B will then be fulfilled either by the edge cache, and won't execute  code at origin to retrieve data for the next request.

[image]

This should be considered separately from the concerns of Service A, which may want to cache the response data for a period of time before making another request to Service B.

The things you want to minimise are the cost of inter process communication (HTTP Call, Service A -> Service B) and the serialization/deserilzation work that requires.

A common pattern here is a read-through cache, where Service A will check for a cached response from an operation before deciding to make a call back to Service B  (which *could* still respond with edge-cached data)

[image]

Service A should decide on it's caching strategy, how long it will cache response in either an instance based MemoryCache or shared cache (e.g. Redis). Service B is probably returning data about some useful object as it's content, serialized in some form - 'A' should deserailize and cache this response.

I would keep the caching requirements for these services seperate, don't use the max-age value to decide how long to cache the response for in Service A. This would introduce a coupling between the services - if the designer of Service B changed the max-age value then this would impact how Service A behaves.

Instead, have a configuration value for Service A that defines how long it is OK to cache responses from Service B, use this to design your read through cache implementation. Store the deserialised responses from Service B in the cache for that period of time

NB - I referenced images from http://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance/caching/response.html and http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/grid-pattern-proactive-caching.html.

Comment: +1 for elaborate answer but I am not sure it is adressing the issue. In your answer, you assume that the "client" will consume `foo` and the `Service A` is a proxy. This is however, not the case. `Service A` needs to consume resources in `Servie B` without interference or interaction with any client. The client will consume resources in `Service A` but will not know about `Foo`, rather it will work with `Bar` which is related to `Foo` but not the same type. Communication without client interference. I am asking how `Service A` will work with Cache-Control on objects retrieved from `Service B`.

Comment: I was assuming direct HTTP communication between Service-A and Service-B, but highlighting the way web proxies will honour the Cache header you are setting. I was also trying to demonstrate that they should be considered as separate things - the Cache-Control headers from Service B should only be used for the intended purpose of HTTP caching, and Service A should not use that value, otherwise you'd introduce a coupling between the services. My advice is don't use Cache-Control headers for cache logic in Service-A, have Service-A maintain a config value that dictates this - rather than ServiceB

Comment: Alright, so basically your answer on how to use Cache-Control in service-to-service architectures is: don´t! :)